# Oracle: using some results as columns headers

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database with two tables as:
table one:

```
Petition - Date
```

table two:

```
Petition - Item - Count
```

So the data is shown as:

```
00000001 - 20171106

00000001 - Apple  - 2
00000001 - Orange - 3
```

The thing is that I would like to make a query where I get the data formatted in this way:

```
Petition - Date     - Apple - Orange
00000001 - 20171106 - 2     - 3
```

I only have been able to make one that shows me data in this way:

```
Petition - Date     - Item   - Count
00000001 - 20171106 - Apple  - 2
00000001 - 20171106 - Orange - 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PIVOT`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/22fb6/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE one ( petition, "Date" ) AS
SELECT '00000001', DATE '2017-11-06' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE two ( petition, item, "Count" ) AS
SELECT '00000001', 'Apple', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '00000001', 'Orange', 3 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   (
  SELECT o.petition,
         o."Date",
         t.item,
         t."Count"
  FROM   one o
         INNER JOIN two t
         ON ( o.petition = t.petition )
)
PIVOT ( SUM( "Count" ) FOR item IN (
  'Apple'  AS Apple,
  'Orange' AS Orange
) ) p
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/22fb6/2/0)**:

```
| PETITION |                 Date | APPLE | ORANGE |
|----------|----------------------|-------|--------|
| 00000001 | 2017-11-06T00:00:00Z |     2 |      3 |
```

Comment: Wonderful, PIVOT was what I was looking for! Got it! Thanks so much!